# Email a form with multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I created a form with a multidimensional arrays and I'm trying to send an e-mail with the arrays using PHPmailer by writing the contents of the arrays to a text file and then having it read the file for contents but when I send the e-mail it only shows up as "'; } fclose(); ?> ". What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of the form with the multidimensional array:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="send_mail_tray.php" onsubmit='return packageValidator()'>
   <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="appetizer[]" value="Appetizer 1" />Appetizer 1</td>
        <td style="width: 75px" align="right">
            Med: <input type="text" name="appetizer[0][Med]" style="width: 30px" /><br />
            Lg: <input type="text" name="appetizer[0][Lg]" style="width: 30px" />
        </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="appetizer[]" value="Appetizer 2" />Appetizer 2</td>
        <td style="width: 75px" align="right">
            Med: <input type="text" name="appetizer[1][Med]" style="width: 30px" /><br />
        Lg: <input type="text" name="appetizer[1][Lg]" style="width: 30px" />
        </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="appetizer[]" value="Appetizer 3" />Appetizer 3</td>
        <td style="width: 75px" align="right">
            Med: <input type="text" name="appetizer[2][Med]" style="width: 30px" /><br />
            Lg: <input type="text" name="appetizer[2][Lg]" style="width: 30px" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      ...
   </table>
   <input type="Submit" value="Submit Order" />
</form>
```

My PHP code:

```
foreach ($_POST['appetizer'] as $piece => $sizes){
    $medSize = $sizes['Med'];
    $lgSize = $sizes['Lg'];
    if(!empty($medSize) || !empty($lgSize)){
        $appetizer .= $_GET['appetizer'] . " - Med: " . $medSize . ", Lg: " . $lgSize;
    }
}

$message = ("<p>Thank you for your catering request!</p>
    <p><b>Name:</b> $name<br />
    <b>Phone #:</b> $phone<br />
    <b>Email:</b> $email</p>
    <p><b>Appetizers:</b><br />
    $appetizer
    </p>");
```

I have also tried using andrewsi's code but after using it, I no longer receive e-mails:

```
foreach ($_POST['appetizer'] as $piece => $sizes){
    $medSize = $sizes['Med'];
    $lgSize = $sizes['Lg'];
    if(!empty($medSize) || !empty($lgSize)){
        $message .= $_GET['appetizer'] . " - Med: " . $medSize . ", Lg: " . $lgSize;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for sending the e-mail:

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = //SMTP server
$mail->Sender = //Sender
$mail->From = //From
$mail->AddReplyTo("email@email.com");
$mail->FromName = //FromName;
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = //Subject;
$mail->Body=$message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Send();
echo"<script>window.location='thankyou.html'</script>";
```

Comment: Is there a reason, by the way, why you're writing to a text file and then emailing from that?

Comment: You don't have to open and close the file in the foreach loop, just before (opening) and after (closing) is fine.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was any other way to print the data after filtering out unused arrays(empty values for sizes). Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: @D-Boy - combine the email code with your file-writing code. Instead of writing to the file, write it to `$message`.

Comment: @andrewsi - I tried putting the foreach code inside $message before which also failed. It was one of the reasons why I thought writing to a file was the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rejig the last piece of code:

```
$message = "<p><b>Appetizers:</b><br />";

$fapp = fopen('appetizers.txt', 'r');
while(!feof($fapp)){
    $message .= fgets($fapp) . '<br />';
}
fclose($fapp);
```

You're mixing code in with your email text - this way, you're separating them out.

Edited to add:

You can also generate `$message` straight from `$_POST`:

```
foreach ($_POST['appetizer'] as $piece => $sizes){
    $medSize = $sizes['Med'];
    $lgSize = $sizes['Lg'];
    if(!empty($medSize) || !empty($lgSize)){
        $message .= $piece . " - Med: " . $medSize . ", Lg: " . $lgSize;
    }
}
```

That will save you writing and then reading a file.

Comment: With this method would I have to make a new variable like $body that contains both $message and $fapp and then set PHPmailer to read the body as "$mail->Body=$body"?

Comment: That code is a direct replacement for your last piece of code above, where you're setting `$message` - you shouldn't need to change anything else.

Comment: The code I posted is not the only code I have, I also have codes for a main course and dessert, I did not include them to save space.

Comment: So you just need to adapt what I've written for those, too.

Comment: I tried using your code and I'm getting a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='" on "$message. = $_GET['appetizer'] . " - Med: " . $medSize . ", Lg: " . $lgSize;"

Comment: I tried using your code but I stopped receiving e-mails. I then tried changing your $message to $appetizer and then add it into my $message and it just shows blank. I'll edit my question to include the code incorporated with your code.

Comment: Editted my question to add the email code. As much as possible I would like to try and keep my $message because as I state before, I will also be adding a main course and dessert array as well as other information(name, phone, email, etc) once I can get the appetizers working.

Comment: No idea if it'll fix it, but I've changed the `$_GET` in the loop to `$_POST`. It won't help, at the least. Can you try a `var_dump($message)` just before you try to send the email to see if there's anything in there?

Comment: It just says "NULL". I guess I'm doing something wrong with getting values for the arrays?

Comment: Are you actually setting any values in your form when you submit it? Try initializing `$message` to "Test" before you start parsing the input, and see then - if it's only showing "Test" at the end, then none of your parsing code is being triggered.

Comment: Yes, I am filling in some values(random numbers) for both sizes. When I initialize $message to "test" before I start parsing, I get "string(4) "test"" so my parsing code is incorrect.

Comment: @D-Boy - try a `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure that the fieldnames you're submitting are the same ones as the parsing code is expecting.

Comment: I'm getting  ...["appetizer"]=> array(96) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Med"]=> string(0) "" ["Lg"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Med"]=> string(0) "" ["Lg"]=> string(0) "" } [2]=> array(2) { ["Med"]=> string(0) "" ["Lg"]=> string(0) "" }... After setting the values to all of those to 4 in the form.

Comment: Try tweaking your submission form - instead of `<input type="hidden" name="appetizer[0]"`, change the name to `appetizer[]`, for each of them.

Comment: Tweaking the form did not change anything.

Comment: Odd. Because when I did it, it works fine for me - it's getting everything from the appetizer section and populating `$_POST` properly. Could you update your question with what the HTML now looks like?

Comment: It seems the code works when I cut out out all the other appetizers, main courses, and desserts besides what I had in my question. I also updated the question with the html. I also just tried doing var_dump($message) and get 'string(80) "Array - Med: 1, Lg: 2
Array - Med: , Lg: 4
Array - Med: 5, Lg: 6
" ' so now the problem I seem to be experiencing is for some reason, the Medium value for the 2nd appetizer is now being read(should be 3) and having the value of the appetizer(Appetizer 1, Appetizer 2, Appetizer 3) show up instead of "Array"

Comment: I've tweaked the answer again, and that should pick up the value of the appetizer. I've no idea why one of the values isn't being picked up - there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the HTML, and if it was an issue with with PHP, we'd be missing more than just the one.

Comment: For some reason the value for Appetizer 2 is being picked up now. Using your updated code, doing var_dump($message) only shows the number of the appetizer(0, 1, 2) and not the value. Am I suppose to be setting the name of the value as another array like "appetizer[][name]"?